# Python - Multiple Rows to unique row and transpose column

Tags: python

Need help on converting data frame from

| productID | Key | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | AB | Yes |
| 123 | BC | Yes |
| 123 | CD | Yes |
| 123 | DE | No |
| 124 | AB | Yes |
| 124 | DE | No |
| 124 | FG | Yes |

to transpose key's as column and copy the status

| ProductID | AB | BC | CD | DE | FG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |  |
| 124 | Yes |  |  | No | Yes |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 'pivot' function from pandas

```py
df = ... # define your dataframe
df.pivot(index='productID',columns='Key',values='Status')
```

Read more about the function here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

In case you want to do the otherway around, the method you will looking for is called `melt` in Pandas

Comment: thanks. pivot was throwing error, used pivot_table, now the issue is I need two index column, Is it possible to add another column in index when we use pivot_table?

Comment: well, pivot_table does accept array/list for index argument, so you can try to pass the list of 2 column names

Comment: worked, thanks again